# When will Ubuntu 18.04 get kernel version 5.3?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, lts

I discussed this in reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/d3xm0d/unable_to_connect_to_google_starbucks_with_ubuntu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) and linux-wireless kernel mailing list [here](https://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&m=157072939630698&w=2).  This issue is specific to the HP hardware and 5.0.0 kernel used in the LTS distro.  The mainline 5.0.21 kernel fixes the issue.

I am just curious if someone can tell me when the 5.3.x kernel will be release for LTS use.  Will appreciate any guesstimate on that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "when will this be released in Ubuntu" isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Agreed but at least we can track "some" things. And that's answerable. I think.

Comment: You can install 5.3 today if you want to.

Comment: Perhaps I should change the title of this post...

Comment: @DavidKWH How would you change the title?

Answer (score 5):

You can install 5.3 at any time on any Ubuntu distribution but that is only recommended when you have new hardware not supported by installed kernels. You can also subscribe to [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) and eventually get 5.3 or even higher.

To install manually you can select from `5.3.1` through `5.3.5` kernels released by Ubuntu:

[image: kernel 5.3.png]

For full instructions (and warnings) see:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

Answer (score 4):

[Bionic (18.04): Ubuntu - Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic) is the official place to track the milestones which Ubuntu developers will be targeting or has been achieved till now.

As per the page linked above, 18.04 will get 19.10's kernel (which is version 5.3) on **February 6, 2020** with the release of 18.04.4.

But if you want kernel version 5.3 now, you can install it using [UKUU](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) but it's not the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Perhaps rewording to indicate running 5.3 is not recommended? People might misunderstand to think UKUU is not recommended and they should install conventionally like this: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well TBH, I generally don't recommend to install kernels that aren't provided as an update by APT.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.04 ([HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)) has the Linux Kernel 5.3 available now, via APT (bionic-updates channel).

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe

Answer (score 2):

Pretty accurate answer:

Ubuntu 20.04 (next LTS) should include the 5.3.x or newer kernel.  Ubuntu 19.10 should also include the 5.3.x kernel but will NOT be LTS.